# Fetching param in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

My goal is to fetch username from a url

Inside app.routing I have route
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard/:username', component: App }
];

inside appp component I'm trying to fetch this username using

```
let username = this.route.snapshot.queryParams["username"];
```

My browser is using `localhost:91/dashboard/john`

username is always `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using it as params

```
let username = this.route.snapshot.params["username"];
```

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `queryParams` here. This is useful when you have something like this:

```
localhost:91/dashboard?username=john
```

Just use `params` property.

```
this.route.snapshot.params["username"];
```

I suppose you declared route in following way:

```
{ path: 'dashboard/:username', component: SomeComponent}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.route.snapshot.params['username']
```

Instead of queryParams